# Is there a way to set properties of an object in the html of an angular ngModel?

Tags: angular

I might be wording this question strangely, but effectively the situation is this:

I have a form that takes a list of questions, and makes a form based on an a ngFor loop. Think

```
ngFor="let question of questions"
```

Within there, I want to bind an answer object I made to have some of the data from that question it's on along with the answer from whatever the user types in the  of my site. Im unsure how to go about setting those properties, or if there was a better practice perhaps?

Comment: In the end you want an object containing `{ question, answer }` ?

Comment: In essence, yeah, that would be a pretty good way of going about it. How would you go about that?

Comment: Follow some tutorials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an object like `{ question, answer }`, you can create an Interface on Typescript:

```
export interface QuestionAndAnswer{
  question: string;
  answer: string;
}
```

And make a list of that interface:

```
public listQuestions: QuestionAndAnswer[] = [];
```

You can insert info in that list or get from API, and if you want the answer dynamic, just wait for the user to input some data, then you can save it in your Object then save in the List of Object.

In the html, you can use just like that:

```
<div ngFor="let item of questions">
  <h1>Here is the question: {{item.question}}</h1>
  <h1>And here is the answer: {{item.answer}}</h1>
</div>
```

That was just an example, i know you don't have the answer yet.